# Java Swing component placement

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Why is it considered bad programming form to place components in swing directly onto the frame and not in a panel? When I add components directly to the frame there doesn't really seem to be any problem so I was wondering why all the learning videos I've seen and even the GUI Window Builder I installed place components in panels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add components directly to the frame using `JFrame#add(Component)`, you are actually adding it to the frame's content pane, which is a JPanel.

Extra panels allows more specific detail, which is why you might see multiple panels. I think the main reason why it would be frowned upon is that you should maintain the "component area" (content pane) and the frame (what habdles the border) seperately to avoid confusion. Personally, I dont care too much, and its more of a personal preference.

As stated before, JFrames come bundled with their own Content Pane, which is used when adding components using `JFrame#add(Component)`. If you're really interested, check out the source code for that method.

Another problem is using the paint method. If you override JFrame's paint method, you risk affecting the border; something that can be avoided using a seperate panel

Comment: Thanks for your straight forward answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above reason,another reason is that the using JFrame's default ContentPane,we can't set borders for the components.Here [an example](http://www.fredosaurus.com/JavaBasics/gui/gui-commentary/guicom-60-contentpane.html)